# If $f$ is continuous, $\sup_{|\lambda|<\omega} |f(\lambda)|=\infty$ then $\lim_{|\lambda| \rightarrow \omega} |f(\lambda)|=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $f:(-\omega,\omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, $\omega>0$ and
$$\sup_{|\lambda|<\omega} |f(\lambda)|=\infty.$$
Can we conclude that
$$\lim_{|\lambda| \rightarrow \omega} |f(\lambda)|=\infty?$$

**My attempt:** Since $f$ is continuous, then for all compact $K \subset (-\omega,\omega)$ we have $\sup_{\lambda \in K} |f(\lambda)| \leq C_K$. In a way, this tells us that the function cannot explode "in the middle" of the interval. However, I could not use the other definitions to obtain the desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit at any interior point cannot be infinity, since the function is continuous, but the limit at the endpoints may not exist. For example, consider the function

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}$$

on the interval $x\in (-1,1)$. The function blows up as $x\to 1$ in an oscillatory way, so the limit as $x\to 1$ does not exist.

If you know what $\limsup$ is, then note that it is true that

$$\limsup_{|\lambda|\to \omega} |f(\lambda)| = \infty.$$

This directly follows from assumptions, since the definition of the limsup is

$$\limsup_{|\lambda|\to \omega} |f(\lambda)| := \lim_{t\to \omega} \sup_{|\lambda|\geq t}|f(\lambda)|.$$

If the limit on the right hand side is not $\infty$, then it contradicts you assumption that the supremum of $|f|$ is infinity.

Comment: Thank you! And what would the proof in this case (with $\limsup$)?

Comment: I added an explanation of this.

Comment: Do you know if there is any characterization of this limit in terms of sequences? For example, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ such that $|\lambda_n|< \omega$, $|\lambda_n| \rightarrow \omega$ and $|f(\lambda_n)|>n$.

Comment: Limit=$\limsup$ in the comment above.